# Paypal Express Checkout capture large amounts (bigger than 10.000$) in many transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, express-checkout

we have integrated Paypal Express Checkout as payment method in a website. We have found out that there is a max amount of 10.000$ or 7000€ limit per transaction. Lucky we read it, because this limit is only in Live environment (in Sandbox there isn´t any limit and it´s working fine).

In order to workaround this, what we are trying to do is:

1. Create a single authorization for total amount (i.e 19.000€).
2. Split the capture in many transactions of max. 6.000€

According to this we would have 3 transactions of 6.000€ and one more transaction of 1.000€.

I don´t know if this is the right approach, anyway we capture the first transaction ok. However, we are getting an "Authorization has already been completed" Paypal error when trying to capture the second transaction.

Do we need to send each capture with different transactionID? How should we do it?

Comment: If you contact PayPal and request an increase they may do it for you.  They'll just ask for details about your business and why you need the increase, and then they'll make a decision.  I've seen them do it before for people.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will do it. However, I would like to solve the problem technically, just in case they decide not to increase it.

Comment: What are you sending for the COMPLETETYPE in your DoCapture request?

Comment: You are right. The problem was the COMPLETETYPE attribute. It should be set to NotComplete instead of Complete in order to accept multiple transactions. However, I have tested with some amounts and I have noticed there is a new maximum amount limit of 60.000€. Over it, I get the same error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments above.

Actually the point is for Andrew Angell.